# Backup IIS6 With PowerShell and WMI

Tags: backup, iis-6, powershell

I am trying to backup IIS6 with PowerShell, I have found the method I am after in WMI's `IISComputer.BackupWithPassword` however when I try to execute it with the following PowerShell:

```
$IISComputer = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2" -Class "IISComputer"
$IISComputer.BackupWithPassword("D:\Backup\Wednesday\", 1, 6, "QUESTTSTS")
```

I am presented with:

```
Exception calling "BackupWithPassword" : "Win32: The parameter is incorrect.

At line:1 char:32
```

Having tried various combinations of brackets, quotes, flags, etc. I haven't really got any further with figuring out why this dosn't work.

Any thoughts on getting this to work, I am aware of iisback.vbs and other mechanisms for doing this. This is as much an excercise as a practicable solution to a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out eventually, the following code works:

```
$HIGHEST_VERSION = 9999
$BACKUP_OVERWRITE = 1
$BACKUP_FORCE = 4
$BACKUP_SAVE_FIRST = 2
$Flags = $BACKUP_OVERWRITE -bor $BACKUP_FORCE
$Password = "WhiskyW4i5kyWh1sky"
$IISComputer = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2" -Class "IISComputer"
$result = $IISComputer.BackupWithPassword("ScriptedBackup", $HIGHEST_VERSION, $BACKUP_OVERWRITE, $Password)
```

I have tried to emulate the variable names from the [TechNet article IisComputer.BackupWithPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525290.aspx) to allow for comparisons. The backup is created in `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\inetsrv\MetaBack` named `ScriptedBackup.MD9999` and `ScriptedBackup.SC9999` these two files can be copied across to another location or backed up by your backup software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IIS6 handy right now.  Check this:
http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/iis/iis6/admin/scr_504.asp

It doesn't appear that you can "mask" the values like you've done with 4+2=6.